# Javascript get unique value of an indented json

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

I have JSON `array of objects` with the following structure:

```
obj: [
    {   
        itemTitle: 'title-a',
        itemTags: [
            { tag: 'tag-a' },
            { tag: 'tag-b' }
        ]                       
    },
    {   
        itemTitle: 'title-b',
        itemTags: [
            { tag: 'tag-c' }
        ]                       
    },
    {   
        itemTitle: 'title-c',
        itemTags: [
            { tag: 'tag-c' },
            { tag: 'tag-b' }
        ]                       
    }
]
```

I need to extract distinct tags value in an array like this `[tag-a, tag-b, tag-c]`
I'll try this approach:

```
const tagsArray = obj.map(elem => elem.itemTags);

var tags = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tagsArray.length; i++) {
    tags.push(tagsArray[i].map(item => item.tag))
}
//tagsArray[0]: [{"tag":"tag-a"},{"tag":"tag-b"}]
//tagsArray[1]: [{"tag":"tag-c"}]
//tagsArray[2]: [{"tag":"tag-c"},{"tag":"tag-b"}]

//tags: tag-a,tag-b,tag-c,tag-c,tag-b

const unique = [...new Set(tags)];
//unique: tag-a,tag-b,tag-c,tag-c,tag-b
```

it does not return distinct values

Comment: _"I have json array of objects..."_ - No. `obj` (which is a terrible name for that content) is an array of objects.

Comment: `Array.prototype.flatMap()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try getting the *tag* in the same loop with `flatMap()` and `map()`

```js
var obj = [
    {   
        itemTitle: 'title-a',
        itemTags: [
            { tag: 'tag-a' },
            { tag: 'tag-b' }
        ]                       
    },
    {   
        itemTitle: 'title-b',
        itemTags: [
            { tag: 'tag-c' }
        ]                       
    },
    {   
        itemTitle: 'title-c',
        itemTags: [
            { tag: 'tag-c' },
            { tag: 'tag-b' }
        ]                       
    }
]
const tagsArray = obj.flatMap(elem => elem.itemTags.map(i=>i.tag));

const unique = [...new Set(tagsArray)];
console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

You are pushing the array into each item in `tagsArray`. The content looks like

```
[["tag-a","tag-b"],["tag-c"],["tag-c","tag-b"]]
```

While you need

```
["tag-a","tag-b","tag-c","tag-c","tag-b"]
```

#### Solution

==> *Using `concat` instead of `push`*

```js
const obj = [{itemTitle:'title-a',itemTags:[{tag:'tag-a'},{tag:'tag-b'}]},{itemTitle:'title-b',itemTags:[{tag:'tag-c'}]},{itemTitle:'title-c',itemTags:[{tag:'tag-c'},{tag:'tag-b'}]}];

var tags = [];
const tagsArray = obj.map(elem => elem.itemTags);
for (var i = 0; i < tagsArray.length; i++)
    tags = tags.concat(tagsArray[i].map(item => item.tag)); // Use concat instead of push
const unique = [...new Set(tags)];
console.log(unique);
```

#### Refactor code

You can use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const obj = [{itemTitle:'title-a',itemTags:[{tag:'tag-a'},{tag:'tag-b'}]},{itemTitle:'title-b',itemTags:[{tag:'tag-c'}]},{itemTitle:'title-c',itemTags:[{tag:'tag-c'},{tag:'tag-b'}]}];

const tagsArray = obj.flatMap(({itemTags}) => itemTags.map(({tag}) => tag));
console.log([...new Set(tagsArray )]);
```

> The `flatMap()` method *returns a new array* formed by applying a given
> callback function to *each element of the array*, and then flattening
> the result by one level

---

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried and it works well. thanks also for the explanation

Comment: Yes, you can accept my answer by clicking the tick to mark it as resolved @riky1 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
let t=arr.flatMap(item=>item.itemTags.flatMap(tag=>Object.values(tag)))
u = new Set([...t])
```